# CORS issue on a POST request using Flask + Typescript

Tags: javascript, python, http, flask, cors

This is part of my python code

```
app/products/__init__.py
bp_products = Blueprint('products', __name__, url_prefix='/products')

@bp_products.route('', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'], endpoint='add')
@bp_products.route('/', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'], endpoint='add')
@json_response
def add():
    if request.json is None:
        abort(400, 'Request must be json')

    # Some logic here

    return product_schema.dump(product)
```

```
app/__init__.py
with app.app_context():
        # Some logic here
        CORS(app)

    from .products import bp_products
    app.register_blueprint(bp_products)
```

All dependencies were properly imported but I didn't add the code here.

For some reason, this code (note the trailing slash)

```
let response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/products/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        asin: productAsin,
        process: 1,
      }),
    });
```

works properly but when I remove the trailing slash, it doesn't work, despite both routes were defined on my code

```
@bp_products.route('', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'], endpoint='add')
@bp_products.route('/', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'], endpoint='add')
```

I tried switching these routes positions, removing the rest of the routes on my code in case there was a conflicting one, removing all the code inside my method in case some code was failing there, specifying headers, methods and routes using CORS config options... none of my attempts were successful.

It's worth noting that this works when I use postman (so the route seems to be properly defined).

The solution may be in front of my eyes but I am not seeing it (it's worth noting I am new to Python).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: " but when I remove the trailing slash, it doesn't work," - what about it doesn't work? What is the network response code and data? Do you receive a particular error message? What makes you think it is CORS related?

Comment: From chrome console: `Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/products' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

From flask debugger: `"OPTIONS /products HTTP/1.1" 415 -`
When the trailing slash is part of the url, this doesn't happen, and the `OPTIONS` request works just fine
`"OPTIONS /products/ HTTP/1.1" 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This decorator `@cross_origin()` made the trick.
Once I added it, both routes started to work (with and without the trailing slash).
I am not sure why this is only necessary for the route without a trailing slash on it. If someone knows the reason, I am eager to know it.

Comment: I had the same problem with CORS and this post gave me the clue.  it was the trailing slash was not in the fetch and the route had one.  I didnt need OPTIONS method or the @cross_origin() decorator.  it was the routes that were wrong but it always gives the impression its CORS trowing you off.